# Mean of 5 X 5 neighbor pixels of raster in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image-processing, gdal

I have multiples raster with pixel resolution 10 X 10 meters and the raster value is in float format and I want to keep the out raster value in float format only.

I want to calculate 5 x 5 window pixel averaging to remove the noise from images and create a smooth raster in python. I worked out on a below code from different sources of stackoverflow, but it not working and its producing error.

I would appreciate any help.

Below Code:

```
import time 
import glob
import os
import gdal
import osr
import numpy as np 

start_time_script = time.clock()

path_ras=r'D:\Firm_SM\F1A/'

for rasterfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_ras,'*.tif')):
    rasterfile_name=str(rasterfile[rasterfile.find('IMG'):rasterfile.find('.tif')])

print ('Processing:'+ ' ' + str(rasterfile_name))

ds = gdal.Open(rasterfile,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
ds_xform = ds.GetGeoTransform()

print (ds_xform)

ds_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('Gtiff')
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
#srs.ImportFromEPSG(4726)

ds_array = ds.ReadAsArray()

sz = ds_array.itemsize

print ('This is the size of the neighbourhood:' + ' ' + str(sz))

h,w = ds_array.shape

print ('This is the size of the Array:' + ' ' + str(h) + ' ' + str(w))

bh, bw = 5,5

shape = (h/bh, w/bw, bh, bw)

print ('This is the new shape of the Array:' + ' ' + str(shape))

strides = sz*np.array([w*bh,bw,w,1])

blocks = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ds_array,shape=shape,strides=strides)

resized_array = ds_driver.Create(rasterfile_name + '_resized_to_52m.tif',shape[1],shape[0],1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
resized_array.SetGeoTransform((ds_xform[0],ds_xform[1]*2,ds_xform[2],ds_xform[3],ds_xform[4],ds_xform[5]*2))
resized_array.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
band = resized_array.GetRasterBand(1)

zero_array = np.zeros([shape[0],shape[1]],dtype=np.float32)

print ('I start calculations using neighbourhood')
start_time_blocks = time.clock()

for i in xrange(len(blocks)):
    for j in xrange(len(blocks[i])):

        zero_array[i][j] = np.mean(blocks[i][j])

print ('I finished calculations and I am going to write the new array')

band.WriteArray(zero_array)

end_time_blocks = time.clock() - start_time_blocks

print ('Image Processed for:' + ' ' + str(end_time_blocks) + 'seconds' + '\n')

end_time = time.clock() - start_time_script
print ('Program ran for: ' + str(end_time) + 'seconds')
```

Error massage:

```
This is the size of the neighbourhood: 4
This is the size of the Array: 106 144
This is the new shape of the Array: (21.2, 28.8, 5, 5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-fbee5d0233b0> in <module>
     21 strides = sz*np.array([w*bh,bw,w,1])
     22 
---> 23 blocks = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(ds_array,shape=shape,strides=strides)
     24 
     25 resized_array = ds_driver.Create(rasterfile_name + '_resized_to_52m.tif',shape[1],shape[0],1,gdal.GDT_Float32)

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in as_strided(x, shape, strides, subok, writeable)
    101         interface['strides'] = tuple(strides)
    102 
--> 103     array = np.asarray(DummyArray(interface, base=x))
    104     # The route via `__interface__` does not preserve structured
    105     # dtypes. Since dtype should remain unchanged, we set it explicitly.

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What you are looking for is convolution with a 5x5 all 1s kernel. There are libraries to support that function.

Comment: Calculates the mean of the cells in the defined neighborhood cell. Suppose, I defined 5 that means the program will consider 5 X 5 pixels and generate a mean value.

Comment: What you explained is what a convolution does.

Comment: yes, its type of method what convolution does